# Автоматическое заполнение поля

Tags: c

Дано поле с расставленными "лисами", по ним должен бить компьютер. Созданы два массива, которые вносят определенные значения в "черный список" (если количество целей в одном столбце и строке - 0, по ним стрелять бессмысленно). Однако, это как-то не помогает, плюс выводится только шесть подстреленных лис. В чем проблема? глобальные переменные пусть не смущают, это только тестовая программа.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int blacklistRow[8], blacklistCol[8];
int indexBlackListRow = 0, indexBlackListCol = 0;

int Win(int* foxes) {
    if((*foxes) == 0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;

}

void OutputField(char fieldForOutput[][8]) {    //вывод поля в консоль
    printf ("\n   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |\n");    //нумерация столбцов
    printf ("------------------------------------");
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        printf("\n%3d|",i+1);   //нумерация строк
        for(j = 0; j<8; j++)
                printf("%2c |", fieldForOutput[i][j]);
        printf("\n------------------------------------");
    }
}

void AutomaticInputField(int field[][8]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, j,
    k = 8;

    for (i = 0; i<8; i++)
        for (j = 0; j<8; j++)
            field[i][j] = 0;    //создание пустого поля для лис

    while (k > 0) {
        i = rand()%8;
        j = rand()%8;
        if(field[i][j] == 0) {
            field[i][j]++;
            k--;
        }
    }
}

void FillFalse(int array[20]) {
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        array[i] = -1;
}

int CheckCoordinates(int index, int blacklist[20]) {
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        if(blacklist[i] == index)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

void AutomaticInputSteps(int field[][8], char fieldForOutput[][8], int* foxes, int* steps) {    //функция самой игры
    int coordinatesRow, coordinatesCol, //координаты
    i, j, foxesOnTheLine = 0;       //foxesOnTheLine - количество лис в одной строке и столбце

    printf("Ходит компьютер...\n\n");

    OutputField(fieldForOutput);
    printf("\nШагов сделано: %d\n", *steps);
    printf("Осталось лис: %d",*foxes);
    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\nstep = %d", *steps);
    #endif

    do{
        coordinatesRow = rand()%8;      //координаты -- рандомные числа 0..7
        coordinatesCol = rand()%8;
    } while(fieldForOutput[coordinatesRow][coordinatesCol] != ' '  && !CheckCoordinates(coordinatesRow, blacklistRow) && !CheckCoordinates(coordinatesCol, blacklistCol));
    //цикл продолжается, пока оба числа не будут удовлетворять условиям: в клетку ранее не били, ни одна из координат не входит в "черный список"

    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("coordinatesRow = %d, coordinatesCol = %d",coordinatesRow,coordinatesCol);
    #endif

    if(field[coordinatesRow][coordinatesCol] != 0) {        //если в поле есть лисы, на экран выводится символ X
        fieldForOutput[coordinatesRow][coordinatesCol] = 'X';
        --(*foxes);
    }
    else {
        for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
            foxesOnTheLine+=field[coordinatesRow][i];       //подчет лис в одной строке 
            foxesOnTheLine+=field[i][coordinatesCol];       //                          и одном столбце
            fieldForOutput[coordinatesRow][coordinatesCol] = (char)48+foxesOnTheLine;   //количество лис как символ
        }
        if(foxesOnTheLine == 0) {
            blacklistRow[indexBlackListRow] = coordinatesRow;
            blacklistCol[indexBlackListCol] = coordinatesCol;
            indexBlackListRow++;
            indexBlackListCol++;
        }
    }
    (*steps)++;
}


void AI_Game(int* foxes, int* steps) {
    int field[8][8];    //поле, значение каждого элемента которого показывает количество лис в данной клетке
    char fieldForOutput[8][8];      //поле для вывода
    int i,j;

    FillFalse(blacklistRow);    //заполнение черного списка -1
    FillFalse(blacklistCol);


    AutomaticInputField(field);
    system("cls");

    for(i = 0; i<8; i++)
        for(j = 0; j<8; j++)
            fieldForOutput[i][j] = ' ';

    while(!Win(foxes)) {    //цикл продолжается до победы
        system("cls");
        AutomaticInputSteps(field, fieldForOutput, foxes, steps);
    }

    system("cls");
    OutputField(fieldForOutput);
    printf("\nВы подстрелили всех лис!");

    _getch();
}

int main() {

    int foxes = 8, steps = 0;
    AI_Game(&foxes, &steps);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в функцию которая обрабатывает 20 элементов массива

```
void FillFalse(int array[20])
```

передается массив из 8 элементов

```
int blacklistRow[8], blacklistCol[8];
....
FillFalse(blacklistRow);    //заполнение черного списка -1
FillFalse(blacklistCol);
```

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо 
Это я уже потом ковырялся, проблему это, увы, не решает. Компьютер продолжает бить в занесённые в чс клетки, плюс некоторые ходы не выводятся вообще.